# Unable to resolve alias in sibling folder using for nextjs project

Tags: webpack, babeljs, next.js

### Background

In my project I'm using [`lerna js`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage the monorepo folder structure and installing process. The folder structure is simple, we have 2 packages called `web` and `common`.

```
package.json
lerna.json
packages
    common
        package.json
    web
        package.json
        next.config.js
        .babelrc
```

### Problem

In order to avoid building a `dist` version every time when developing in the `common` package I've added an `include` property to the webpack rule that is used to compile `js` code. This works perfect and without issue.

The issue however is that when I want to add an alias to the imported code from `common`, it doesn't apply it when compiling. The code that I need to implement requires adding this alias for it to work ([`react-native-web-maps`](https://github.com/react-native-web-community/react-native-web-maps/#getting-started)).

**Some issues that might be related**

- [Babel 7 ignores files outside of project directory](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8309)
- [Plugin don't resolve aliases out side working directory](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/361)
- [Webpack with babel-loader don't process js files from sibling directories](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3014)
- [Config: Rule test should respect module alias](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4678)

### Tried solutions

I've been trying for multiple full days to get this to work but so far no success. Below are the things I've tried so far:

- Adding `babel.config.js` to the root by using [next-transpile-modules plugin](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) and [next-plugin-custom-babel-config](https://github.com/josephluck/next-plugin-custom-babel-config)
- Adding `alias` to the webpack config in `next.config.js`, works inside `web` but not for imports of files from `common`
- Messing around with `root` and `rootMode` (I have no real understanding on how to properly use these)

### Code snippets

#### `next.config.js` (webpack options for `next.js`)

```js
const path = require("path");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withImages = require("next-images");

const aliases = {
    common: path.join(__dirname, "../common/"),
    "react-native": "react-native-web",
    "react-native-maps": "react-native-web-maps"
};

const includePaths = [path.resolve(__dirname, "../common/")];

const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        // Add aliases
        config.resolve.alias = {
            ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
            ...aliases
        };

        // Also transpile files from common/...
        config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
            rule.include = [...(rule.include || []), ...includePaths];
            return rule;
        });

        return config;
    }
};

module.exports = withPlugins([withImages], nextConfig);
```

#### `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "root": ["./", "./../common/"],
                "alias": {
                    "react-native": "react-native-web",
                    "react-native-maps": "react-native-web-maps",
                    "common": "./../common/src/"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

#### `packages/common/src/component.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native-web";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

const Component = ({ coordinates }) => (
    <View>
        <MapView region={{ latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude }}>
            <MapView.Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: coordinates.latitude,
                    longitude: coordinates.longitude
                }}
            />
        </MapView>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Hi there, have you solved it in some way that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to build the `common` package with the aliases into a `packages/common/dist` folder, then tell the `web` package to read from the build module instead of reading from `common`'s source. Treat it like a module. It's an extra step, but I fear it's the only solution. Pros and cons to the mono-repo/lerna architecture I guess..

What I mean is inside common:

```
lerna.json
packages/
    common/
        dist/
        package.json
        webpack.config.js
        .babelrc
    web/
        package.json
        next.config.js
        .babelrc
```

1)

Set up your `packages/common/webpack.config.js` to map the aliases. This does mean you have to manage 2 aliases in your monorepo. But they are 2 separate packages with 2 separate configs so in this way, the DRY doesn't really make sense.

```js
// packages/common/webpack.config.js
{
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "react-native": "react-native-web",
      "react-native-maps": "react-native-web-maps"
    }
  }
...
}
```

2)

Build the `common` package with this webpack config into `packages/common/dist`. You might have to build it on every deployment in case you don't want to check `packages/common/dist` into source control.

3)

In `packages/web/next.config.js`, read from this freshly built package which has the correct aliases:

```js
// packages/web/next.config.js
const aliases = {
    common: path.join(__dirname, "../common/dist/"),
    "react-native": "react-native-web",
    "react-native-maps": "react-native-web-maps"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, so there is no way around this? :( I feel that this is a lot of setup/building/waiting every time. For example in storybook (which is setup at the root) it is working with the aliases...

Comment: I am not really aware of any other way. I am not sure how storybook is working either.. maybe it has something to do with the `includes` option of one of the loaders? Often you come across this issue when importing modules in a monorepo and the loader's config only applies to files within that package's directory.

Comment: Of course with lerna you can setup a `lerna build` script which will build all your packages (in this case, only `common`) so it's not really much of an overhead.